# throwing 2 dice probability

Tags: probability

I am throwing $2$ dices and I want the sum of the two dices to be $> 8$

Now the dice is from $1$ to $6$ so to get $>8$ we have $9 - 12$

$ 6 + 6$   $ 5 + 6$ $ 4 + 6$

$ 6 + 5$   $ 5 + 5$ $ 4 + 5$

$ 6 + 4$   $ 5 + 4$ $ 3 + 6$

$ 6 + 3$

so it should be that you only have $4$ options out of $6$ for the first dice and then it should be $2$ for the other dice because we can always find $2$ numbers to combine with.
For an example if we land on a $4$ we have either $5$ or $6$ to combine with however what if we land on $6$ then we have $4$ other options but that is not always the case.

$4/6 * 2/6 = 8/36$

In my book it says it should be $10/36$ what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there are four possibilities for the first roll ($3$, $4$, $5$, oe $6$). But then depending on the first roll there are different numbers of possibilities for the second roll.  If you roll $3$ on the first roll, the only possibility for the second roll is $6$.  If you roll $4$ on the first roll, then the second roll could be $5$ or $6$. And so on.

Try to finish it up from here!

Comment: ok managed to solve it some clumsy mistakes on my part had to many combinations